# jQuery ajax call to receive text/plain

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using this jQuery AJAX call to google's ClientLogin.

```
$.ajax({ url:"https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin", 
         type:"POST", 
         data:{'Email': 'myusername', 
               'Passwd': 'mypassword', 
               'service': 'fusiontables', 
               'accountType': 'HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE'}, 
         dataType:"jsonp", 
         success:function(data){ console.log("Hurrah!"); }, 
         error:function(e){ console.log(e); }
});
```

The problem is, ClientLogin does not return a JSON, rather a text/plain. So I get the following error:

```
SID=blahblah
LSID=blahblah
Auth=blahblah
```

ClientLogin:3 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL.

How can I parse this response and get the Auth= value?

Comment: Have you tried to add ?alt=json to the URL or pass it as data?

Comment: what browser you are trying from? some modern browsers don't let make AJAX call to third-party applications for security reasons.

Comment: @Antonio I just did. Doesn't seem to work.
@Muneer Google Chrome. I know I can modify a menifest file, but this is a script in a html file.

Comment: diving through the Google Api, it seems you are using the wrong format to "attack" the API. As far as I could understand, you need to use OAuth 2.0 for client-side web applications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON-P wraps data in JavaScript to get around the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

You **can't** read arbitrary data from third party websites with client side JavaScript.

Proxy the data through your own server if you want it.

Comment: I tried that. But then I get a XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't noticed that. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a PHP proxy dedicated for this use. Make the Ajax call to your PHP proxy withing your domain. Then use the php curl function to get authenticated from Google.